# Safari 9.1.3 border width issue

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit

So I am not sure what is going on, but in Safari 9.1.3, the border width on elements with a certain combination of other styles is creating unexpected results.  Basically, I am applying a transform on an absolutely positioned element to get horizontal centering on a variable width element.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="border">
    <div class="border__text">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.border {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.border__text {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot of border issue in Safari 9.3.1]

**Codepen**

[Try this in Safari 9.3.1](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jradxq)

I can get it to work if I change the font size to 11 or 13 pixels, but I would like it to be 12 and I can get it to work if I remove the transform, but I'm not sure of an easy way to center an absolutely positioned element without it.

Comment: As the reason is the transform, why do you need to use it to center the div?

Comment: @LGSon I am centering it horizontally.  The transform is needed to adjust the position after the `position: absolute;` and `left: 50%;`

Comment: If you do like this your problems is gone: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKARVL

Comment: Did my answer solved your question?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `transform`, do like this

```css
.border {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.border__text {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
}
```

```html
<div class='border'>
  <div class='border__text'>test</div>
</div>
```